# Is there a way to make B<Double>, a subclass of A<Number>, be cast as A<Number>?

Tags: java, generics

I've written a bit of generic code for operating with different types of data, but I'm struggling with the numeric data.

I have a class layout like so:

```
public abstract class A<Number> {
  .
  .
  .
}

public class B extends A<Double>{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

however, I cannot use `B` as an `A<Number>`, even though `B` is a subclass of `A<Double>`, which should be a subclass of `A<Number>`.

What am I missing? What would the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should search for co-variance and contra-variance I think. Basically just because `Double` **is** a `Number`; doesn´t mean `Derived<Double>` is also `Base<Number>`.

Answer (score 1):

`B` can't be a `A<Number>` because if you had a method that looked like `void doSomething(T)` then it would not accept an `Integer` (whereas `T returnSomething` would work, as `Double` is assignable to `Number`).

You *can* assign a `B` to a `A<? extends Number>`, however. That means "the generic type is *some unknown subtype* of `Number`", which is often what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`public abstract class A<Number>` has nothing to do with the `java.lang.Number` class.

`Number` is the name of your type parameter. If you meant to make your `A` class generic with a `Number`-related type parameter, then you probably needed something like

```
public abstract class A<T extends Number>
```

Where `T` is your type parameter that forces type arguments to be `java.lang.Number` or one of its subclasses. With this, you should be able to use:

```
A<Double> b = new B(); //with your current declaration of B
```

Now, with that said:

> even though `B` is a subclass of `A<Double>`, which should be a subclass of `A<Number>`.

No, `B<java.lang.Number>` would not be compatible with `A<java.lang.Double>`. You can only use the same type argument on parent and child.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.